# Кончилась длина long long в с++

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long long fac_1(int k1){
if(k1==0){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return k1*fac_1(k1-1);
}
}
int main(){
long long n,k,a,b;
cin >> n>>k;
a=n+k-1;
b=n+k-2;
for(int y=1;n-1>y;y++){
    a=a*b;
    b--;
}
cout <<(a/fac_1(n-1));
}
```

Есть такой код, суть его в том чтобы определить сколько способами можно положить k предметов в n коробок - C(n+k-1,k). Проблема в том, что n+k<=60 и при значениях близким к 30 long long кончается, можно ли это как-то пофиксить?

Comment: Входные данные добавьте что бы воспроизвести вашу проблему

Comment: Немного можно поднять, если считать умнее... Но все равно там, где результат в long long не влезет (примерно при 65) — нужна длинная арифметика.

Answer (score 10):

Воспользуйтесь соотношениями:

```
C(k, k) = 1
C(n, k) = n * C(n - 1, k) / (n - k)
```

Получается что какое количество дробей ни возьми произведение всегда целое:

```
k + 1   k + 2   k + 3         k + i
----- * ----- * ----- * ... * ----- * ...
  1       2       3             i
```

Что приводит к такой процедуре:

```
unsigned long long cnk(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k) {
    unsigned long long p = 1;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= n - k; ++i) {
        p = p * (k + i) / i;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Переполнения не будет пока `n <= 62`. Это решение можно улучшить до оптимального: если результат помещается в разрядную сетку мы его вычислим.

Проблема кода выше - это переполнение произведения `p * (k + i)`. Избавимся от него. Пусть известно что `a * b / c` - целое, тогда

```
a * b / c = (a / НОД(a, c)) * (b / (c / НОД(a, c)))
```

В правой части все частные целые и нет переполнения (мы предполагаем что результат левой части в тип помещается).

Получается такое решение:

```
unsigned long long gcd(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b) {
    while (b > 0) {
        unsigned long long c = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }
    return a;
}

// a * b / c
unsigned long long mul_div(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long c) {
    unsigned long long ac = gcd(a, c);
    return (a / ac) * (b / (c / ac));
}

unsigned long long cnk(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k) {
    unsigned long long p = 1;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= n - k; ++i) {
        p = mul_div(p, i + k, i);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Оно может вычислить `Cnk` для любых комбинаций `n` и `k` для которых результат помещается в разрядную сетку. Например любые `n <= 67`:

> cnk(67, 33) = 14226520737620288370

Последняя вещь которую нужно сделать - уменьшить число итераций если `n` очень велико, а `k` мало. В таком случае будем заменять `k` на `n - k`:

```
unsigned long long cnk(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k) {
    if (k < n - k) {
        k = n - k;
    }
    unsigned long long p = 1;
    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i <= n - k; ++i) {
        p = mul_div(p, i + k, i);
    }
    return p;
}
```

Программа максимум достигнута - если результат помещается в 64 бита он будет вычислен.

Максимальные `n` для небольших `k`:

> ```
> cnk(18446744073709551615,  0) =                    1
> cnk(18446744073709551615,  1) = 18446744073709551615
> cnk(          6074001000,  2) = 18446744070963499500
> cnk(             4801280,  3) = 18446738006366306560
> cnk(              145056,  4) = 18446483332847246040
> cnk(               18580,  5) = 18442234518422931216
> cnk(                4868,  6) = 18426048264474788224
> cnk(                1913,  7) = 18399302838933135756
> cnk(                 967,  8) = 18419736117819661560
> cnk(                 577,  9) = 18348006354228436600
> cnk(                 386, 10) = 17991165343481265936
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Вы пытаетесь посчитать выражение `C(m,n) = n! / ((n-m)! * m!)`
Очевидно, что факториал растет быстро и напрямую немного плохо.

Но давайте посмотрим на эту часть `n!/m!` (у нас `n>m`). Если расписать, то это `(1*2*...*(n-1)*n) / (1*2*...*(m-1)*m)` - а это просто `(m+1) * (m+2) * ... * n`. Если m и n близкие числа, то это легко.

Теперь получается вот так `((m+1) * (m+2) * ... * n) / (1*2*....*(n-m))`. Обычно это уже можно посчитать и для 99% олимпиадных задач достаточно. И это легко закодировать.

```
long long int C(int n, int m)
{
    long long int a = 1;
    for (int i = m+1; i<=n; i++) a = a*i;
    long long int b = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= (n-m); i++) b = b*i;
    return a/b;
}

C(35,25)=183579396
C(40,30)=847660528
```

но вот `C(50,30)` оно уже не хочет...

И тут упираемся, то можно сделать очередной трюк - просто множить "верхние числа" и потихоньку делить "на подходящее нижнее". Под подходящим имеется ввиду такое, на которое делится без остатка.

Но если пойти ещё дальше, то можно разложить на множители верхнее и нижнее произведение и потом поудалять немного. Хотя перед тем как удалять, можно просто сверить два списка, там вполне могут быть уже одинаковые числа.

я сел и накодил такое решение. Оно немного странное, но зато рабочее:)

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

// раскладывает на множители. Да, она супер неэффективная
// но у нас числа до 100 и этого более чем достаточно.
// для 10 она вернет { 2 5 }
// для 12 => { 2 2 3 }
// но можно взять и просто руками захардкодить
std::multiset<int> divid(int n)
{
    std::multiset<int> r;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        while (n%i == 0) {
            n = n / i;
            r.insert(i);
        }
    }
    if (n != 1) r.insert(n);
    return r;
}

// эта функция получает два множества и просто вычитает одно с другого.
// тут куча странных функций, но лучше читать документацию:)
// да, вместо мультисета можно было бы использовать map<int,int>
// ключ - делитель, значение - кол-во, но это на любителя
unsigned long long int C1(int n, int m)
{
    std::multiset<int> a;
    for (int i = m+1; i<=n; i++) { auto x = divid(i); a.insert(x.begin(), x.end());}
    std::multiset<int> b;
    for (int i = 1; i <= (n-m); i++) { auto x = divid(i); b.insert(x.begin(), x.end());}
    std::multiset<int> r;
    std::set_difference(a.begin(),a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(r,r.begin()));
    return std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), 1ull, std::multiplies<unsigned long long int>());  
}

C1(50,30) = 47129212243960
C1(60, 20) = 4191844505805495
```

Comment: В вашем коде при 2 2 выходит 1, должно быть три так как может быть 2 в 1 2 в 2 и по одному в двух.

Comment: в соседнем ответе для 2 2 тоже даст 1 и это правильный ответ. Вам же нужно вычислить значение C(n+k-1,k) = С(2+2-1,2) = С(3,2) что как раз и равно 3.

Comment: Ну это я понимаю, но ваша программа выводит в функции C1 при значениях n,k = 2, 2 - 1 а нужно 3

Comment: нет, не понимаете:) моя функция С1 считает именно С (она так была названа, потому что у меня это было все в одном файле и я тестировал на равенство с предыдущей)